# Extra fields in 'manage display' for content types

Tags: 7, entities, display-suite

On my old website, there were extra fields such as 'Author', 'Last modified', 'Tags', 'Post date', 'Read more', 'User picture', and 'Comments' available in the 'manage display' section of content types.

I'd like to have these fields on my new website too, but I really can't remember anymore how they got there. Does anyone perhaps know if they were provided by a certain module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds), you have to first save the layout you're going to use, then the fields will appear.

Under the "Current Template" section, "None" is probably selected. For a default display, select the "One Column layout" and click save. These fields should then populate.

Comment: Indeed, the fields appeared after I changed the layout to 'One Column' and saved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[Display Suit](https://drupal.org/project/ds) provides those extra fields.

Comment: I already thought so, but I wasn't sure. Are they activated automatically when Display Suit is installed? They don't want to appear...